# Android - Open Facebook app for Logout

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, logout

Is it possible to open Facebook App for logout or logout another way from it if I've login in my app with SSO and now I want to logout?

Comment: post some code for using login?

Comment: Clear Question Yields Good Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can force facebook auth dialog to show next time user tries to log in into your app even though he still would be logged in under his account in Facebook app at that moment.

```
facebook.authorize(activity, FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, facebookDialogListener);
```